# Trying to authenticate with Foursquare but getting an invalid callback uri error

Tags: redirect, oauth-2.0, localhost, foursquare

When I try to authenticate with Foursquare, I get this error message:

> Connecting failed
>
> This app has a configuration problem and was unable
>   to connect to your Foursquare account.
>
> Cause of error: Callback uri is not valid for this consumer

This only happens when I try to redirect to localhost. I am able to successfully authenticate when redirecting to an externally hosted domain. But I'd like to be able to develop on localhost. What is it about localhost that is causing this error?

This is the page that prompts the user to authenticate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <title>O hai</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <a href="https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate?client_id=[myclientid]&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/welcome.html">Authenticate!</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does the callback URI you provide in your app settings page match exactly your `redirect_uri` param? The field in settings should be exactly "http://localhost:8000/welcome.html" and not "http://localhost:8000/" or anything like that.

Comment: Yes, my callback URI in the Foursquare app settings is exactly the same.

Comment: @user374372 How did u solve the issue ? What was the problem ? Can you please share the solution.

Answer (score 1):

To develop on localhost make sure you have all three URLs under Web addresses (your app page at https://foursquare.com/developers/apps) pointing to your localhost app:

```
Download / welcome page url
http://localhost:8000/

Your privacy policy url
http://localhost:8000/

Redirect URI(s)
http://localhost:8000/complete/foursquare/
```

In above example redirect URI is set to work with python social auth and you'll have to change it to your endpoint where you process response from Foursquare.

Answer (score 0):

Try change http to https. I had similar problem and that worked for me.

Comment: I did actually try that before; it got further than with just http but returned an SSL error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a url for redirection that is not publicly available. Foursquare server doesn't know who is localhost.

Comment: that is not correct, foursquare works with localhosts.